# Find line of code which send Error Message in RF Transactions

Tags: abap

How do we check what message number and type is the one being raised in the RF Transaction? Example: ZRF_TRANSACTION raised 'No stock. Deficit of XXX in XXX'. How do I know where to put breakpoint to debug--when I don't know what message number and type is this message?

Comment: What does the message you get look like...? This question is rather basic, so I'm not entirely sure I understood you correctly...

Comment: hi @vwegert. A normal message that appears in RF transactions. Atleast 6liner of message, a little input field on the bottom left but blank and a pushbutton labeled [ f1 continue ].

Comment: look in the code for the text "message".  that's where you need to put breakpoints.  Just put a breakpoint at all of those statements and see which one is hit.

Comment: I have no idea what "Atleast 6liner" is supposed to mean, but I suppose a screenshot might be in order...

Comment: What the heck is an RF transaction?! You don't suppose that everybody knows what your custom transaction ZRF_TRANSACTION is, do you?

Comment: ZRF_TRANSACTION @Jagger is a 'for example' transaction.. don't mind the name. Just the issue.

Comment: @JacobLevinson, i am suspecting that it is a message from standard BAPI being called in the transaction, that is why i am looking for easier way to point out which message number it is.

Comment: Hi guys. I now know the message number via debug mode. It is M7249 of BAPI_GOODSMVT_CREATE. What I was trying to know is since I don't have debug authorization yesterday, I'd like to know how will I check or know what message number the one being raised without debugging. Thanks.

Comment: When you run the transaction in the SAPGui, not on the RF gun, and get the message at the bottom, double click on it and it will tell you. That is if the transaction generates a message, which I doubt, if the program just `WRITE`s out the message there is no way to figure it out without access to the code.

Comment: Hi @GertBeukema--unfortunately, the RF transaction I am dealing with does not generate the message at the bottom like a SAPGui but it is similar to RF gun device when displaying message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gert is right.  Easiest way is to run the RF tcode in sap.  There is another way though if this is somehow not possible.  Look at table T100 in tcode se16 or se16n. You might be able to narrow the message number down to a few or 1 message by passing in the generic parts of the message as a search pattern.  for instance, *No stock* gave me 70 results.  *Deficit of* gave me 4 results.  So, in your example, I think you are getting two different messages sent together.

[image: Search Pattern]

[image: Results]